# Kafka on Docker and Spring Producer Application

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I'm trying to configure the Kafka on Docker and Spring.

The spring application is responsible for producing messages. Docker should consume them. I have prepared container and I am trying to connect.

Unfortunately, I get an error:

```
[Producer clientId=1-1] 1 partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener, including [myTopic-0]
```

My docker-component

```
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    container_name: zookeeper
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    container_name: kafka
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
     KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
     KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
     KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
```

My Spring Configuration

[image]

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

I think your listener's address is not configured well. It should be localhost or the actual docker host name.

This is a working example from my project. Note that I use the original confluence image, but it should work with wurstmeister's image too:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper
    hostname: zookeeper
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: "2181"
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: "2000"
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: "zookeeper:22888:23888"
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka
    hostname: kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_UI:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://kafka:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_BROKER_RACK: "r1"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE: "true"
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "true"
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
      - 29092:29092
```

Comment: I have got error : org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Unable to parse PLAINTEXT_HOST://: to a broker endpoint

Comment: Uh sry, i forgot to replace the advertised listener's environment vars, i edited the code.

Comment: Ok, now get in kafka producer console message "[Producer clientId=producer-1] Cluster ID: MXAUhLOFRmuP9JSMUVi7Ow" -> Is it means that it works ? How can I check is message has been sent ?

Comment: there are many tool you can use, console customer or Kafka tool (GUI) for example: `https://www.kafkatool.com/`

Answer (score 0):

Using bitnami stack

```
version: '3'

services:
  zookeeper:
    container_name: zookeeper
    image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:3.4.14'
    ports:
      - '2181:2181'
    volumes:
      - 'zookeeper_data:/bitnami'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
    restart: unless-stopped
  kafka:
    container_name: kafka
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:2.3.0'
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
    volumes:
      - 'kafka_data:/bitnami'
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    restart: unless-stopped

volumes:
  zookeeper_data:
    driver: local
  kafka_data:
    driver: local
```

Check their guide - there are a lot of insights on how it works + Kafka cluster + more

https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/kafka

Answer (score 0):

My docker-compose file:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  zookeeper:
    container_name: zookeeper
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.3.1
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    volumes:
      - zookeeper-data:/var/lib/zookeeper/data
      - zookeeper-log:/var/lib/zookeeper/log

  kafka:
    container_name: kafka
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.3.1
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "29092:29092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-127.0.0.1}:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    volumes:
      - kafka-data:/var/lib/kafka/data

volumes:
  zookeeper-data:
  zookeeper-log:
  kafka-data:
```